# Nonhomogeneous Poisson Process question

Tags: statistics

I just have a quick question about the nonhomogeneous poisson process.

Say I am looking for E[N(1)|N(2) = 4] where N(t) is the number of arrivals by time t.

Since N(1) is before N(2),

is $$ E[N(1) | N(2) = 4] = E[N(1)] $$

?

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not true. To generalize your question a little, you are asking if the value of $N(2)$ has any influence on the value of $N(1)$, and it certainly has. I can write up the similar expression

$E[N(1) | N(2) = 0].$

In this case, you *know* that at time $2$, you have had no arrivals, and since $N(1)\leq N(2)$, you also know that you must have $N(1)=0$. This means that

$E[N(1) | N(2) = 0]=0.$

On the other hand, you have that

$E[N(1)] = \lambda_1,$

where $\lambda_1$ is the Poisson parameter of $N(1)$, so the two expressions are not equal.

Concerning your case, given that you know $N(2)=4$, you must have that the value of $N(1)$ is some number in the set $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$, so $N(1)|N(2)=4$ is no longer Poisson, since it can take only a finite number of values.

I hope this helps.